# Spam as an answer?

Tags: discussion

I have seen [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/537322) posted at around 7 places and all answers are at least 2 years old. How come this hasn't been deleted yet? It even has some upvotes.

Comment: It's [not spam](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12174/definition-of-spam). I guess "not an answer" is the only valid flag on that.

Comment: Although it is not an answer, I absolutely agree with Will's intent in posting it. Posts like this one are completely antithetical to the goal of Project Euler.

Comment: Also, it's extremely curious how you and another user came to post about this same issue within [15 minutes of each other](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27751/is-this-answer-a-spam-or-what-how-to-deal-with-it). Especially since, as you say, these answers are years old.

Comment: @user296602 It was in the review queue.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Also, I'd suggest closing the other one as a duplicate of this one, since this one has already been answered.

Answer (score 7):

The intended purpose of the answer-post was to explain, in detail, why this question should not be posted on this site.

It is likely not really appropriate as an answer post, but it is certainly not spam (in a narrow sense) and not even in a wider sense as the information is actually pertinent to the question-thread.

To compress the same info into one or two comments would likely have been better.

Comment: FWIW, it seems to be the usual to post an answer trying to discourage questions which violate the rules of active problem solving contests. I'm personally in favor of this, even if they aren't answers in the strictest sense - they convey important information about the question in a way that is far more visible than a comment.

Comment: I think the question should have been voted to close stating the correct reasons.

Comment: @user296602 it's tolerated for externals usually (that cannot comment), but I'd not know it's a common thing to do for regular users. (It's possible I missed it though.)